# Parsing a Custom Search Criteria Grammar in C#

Tags: c#, parsing

In a C# app, I would like users to be able to enter search criteria in this kind of format:

```
(Name = 'Fred' OR Name = 'Jim') AND Age > 30
```

What I need is some way to parse the input so I can test potential search matches against the criteria. I did experiment with [Malcolm Crowe's compiler tools for .NET](http://cis.paisley.ac.uk/crow-ci0/) years ago, but I'm wondering if there is any new stuff I should be aware of in these days of DSLs and expression trees. What is the best way of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been looking at [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/), recently. It's almost overpowered for what you need, but does fall into the category of "new stuff I should be aware of".

[Here's an example](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Full-Text+Search+%282008%29/64248/), using Irony, which seems to do what you require (registration required to read it, though).

Answer (score 1):

Another tool you could use if you have a standardized grammer for you search criteria would be MGrammer which has several tools available for helping to structure the parsing.  A good link for information that is to [Scott Hanselman's Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixGettingMyHeadAroundOsloMAndMGrammar.aspx).  There are also some sample videos of how to use it there.